# Can a Windows 8 / Windows Store app run on Windows Mobile?

Tags: windows

I m new in windows store development. I have 1 basic question.
I have just created one normal application in the VS12-> Windows Store.
Can I run that application on Mobile as well as on windows tablet.
I mean what ever application is developed in the WINDOWS STORE, can we run that application on mobile as well as on tablet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use a less vague title in the future so that others with the same question can find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You will need to download the Windows Phone 8 SDK and create a Windows Phone 8 version of your app and then publish your phone app to the store.

If your app is relatively simple, it shouldn't take much to port it, but you'll need to make sure your UI is designed appropriately for the phone UI experience.

**[Update 2016-05-03]**
Much has changed since I originally answered this question. Microsoft is moving towards Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps which will run on everything from a phone through tablets, laptop/desktop to HoloLens and IoT!

For more information, start [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/whats-a-uwp?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to develop a software targeting the Windows Phone Platform, you must
1 : download the Windows phone SDK ( http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471 : you doxwnload the tiny downloader which helps you download the 1.6 Go File !)
2 : you create, in VS 2012, and only on Windows 8, a project with the new installed Windows Phone Template.